# Better use of conditional render with SetState (React Native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, conditional-statements, render, setstate

I'm rendering a list of products according to a specific value. I'm doing the render with a Picker Component and when it's different of 306, I'm loading the selected products but IF I come back on the first PickerItem (306) I want to show ALL the products again...
For instance :

```js
if (Value != '306') {
        this.setState({
            // isAll: false,
            labels,
            Colours: Value,
            filteredProducts: this.state.displayProducts.filter(product => product.colour == Value)
        }, () => {
            this.onLoadFilteredLabels();
        });
    } else {
        this.setState({
            // isAll: true,
            Colours: Value,
            displayProducts: this.state.products,
            displayLabels: this.state.labels
        });
    }
```

I'm looking for some advice if there is a better way of doing this ?
Do you think I should separe every setState ?
It's working but I have the feeling that it's a bit tricky and I'm still learning. So I know I can have goods advices here with people here !

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of ternary operator, equality check etc. So that your code will look clean. For example,

```js
this.setState({
  isAll: Value === '306',
  filterProducts: Value === '306' ? [yourFilterProducts] : [] 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest approach is to create a custom object for setting states and just passing arguments in a custom method. Apart from that, using ternary could be beneficial:

```js
let stateObj = value === '306' ? {obj : {
            // isAll: true,
            Colours: Value,
            displayProducts: this.state.products,
            displayLabels: this.state.labels
        }, func : () => {
            return false;
        }} : {obj : {
            // isAll: false,
            labels,
            Colours: Value,
            filteredProducts: this.state.displayProducts.filter(product => product.colour == Value)
        }, func : () => {
            this.onLoadFilteredLabels();
        }}

this.stateSetter(stateObj);
```

Next define your custom method:

```js
stateSetter = (stateObj) => {
  let {obj, func} = stateObj; 
  this.setState(obj,func);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally, it's ok if you have several `setState()` calls in different branches of a condition.

But in your case, it's better to update in the state only `Colours` and filter products directly inside the `render` method:

```js
render() {
  const {products: allProducts, Colours} = this.state;
  const displayProducts = Value != '306' ? allProducts.filter(product => product.colour == Colours) : allProducts;

  return (
    <div>
      {displayProducts.map(product => <YourProductComponent key={product.id} product={product}/>)}
    <div>
  );
}
```

React documentation recommends that if you can calculate required data from state or/and props you should do it instead of introducing new prop or state variable.

PS: there's a common recommendation to not to refer to `this.state` when in `setState()`.
React runs `setState` in batch so you can end up with referring to outdated state. You should pass a function as the first argument of `setState`. More details [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate).